# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to import and use plotly

Tags: windows, python-3.x, plotly

I am running a flask application using plotly for some of my charting figures, and it runs fine on my work pc.

I have just tried to run it on my personal pc and on starting the local host server I am getting the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 14, in <module>
    from plotly.offline import plot
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from plotly import (plotly, dashboard_objs, graph_objs, grid_objs, tools,
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from . plotly import (
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line 29, in <module>
    from plotly import exceptions, files, session, tools, utils
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 403, in <module>
    @utils.template_doc(**get_config_file())
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 241, in get_config_file
    ensure_local_plotly_files()  # make sure what's there is OK
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 94, in ensure_local_plotly_files
    utils.save_json_dict(fn, contents)
  File "C:\Users\StuJ7\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\utils.py", line 61, in save_json_dict
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\StuJ7\\.plotly\\.credentials'
```

So it's obvious from the error message that it is an issue with permissions regarding the .plotly.credentials file - but I have assigned myself full permissions to the whole .plotly folder through the security settings and I have also pip installed plotly as an administrator.

I've tried extensive Googling , but there doesn't seem to be much windows related advice regarding this particular issue.

Can anyone suggest how I can get this to work.

Comment: Can you try opening the file manually via python?

Comment: I can not - I get IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fdaa29018b9b> in <module>()
----> 1 fo = open("C:\Users\StuJ7\.plotly\.credentials", "wb")

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\StuJ7\\.plotly\\.credentials'

Comment: Maybe it's a directory. What do you get for `os.stat("C:/Users/StuJ7/.plotly/.credentials")`?

Comment: From that command I get nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=121L, st_atime=1471985187L, st_mtime=1472073690L, st_ctime=1471985187L)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu as well. The problem was that after installing kaleido via pip, the executable files weren't set to be executable in the filesystem. I had to explicitly run a 'chmod +x' on these two files:

/home/[user]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaleido/executable/kaleido
/home/[user]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaleido/executable/bin/kaleido